# Navigator.push throw unhandled exception inside onTap witth async

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, navigation

I have quick question, why can't I use Navigator.push inside `onTap` when `async` is there. Removing the `async` and `await` functions works fine. And Navigator.push works as it is supposed to work. but with the future function call inside onTap I can't Navigate to new class.

```dart
  onTap: () async {
       String _courierOrderID = await model.placeCourierOrder(widget.orderInfoMap);
    // placeCourierOrder is just a Future<String> type function and it works fine. Order get placed successfully.
  
print("------- Courier Order Placed  " + _courierOrderID.toString());
print("context: " + _courierOrderID.toString());
  
  Navigator.push(context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CourierOrderSummaryView(singleCourierDataID: _courierOrderID),
                 ),
               );
             },
```

**Output**
From below output of code, you can see my order placed successfully but on `Navigator.push` line it gives Unhandled exception

```dart
------- Courier Order Placed  501-1c614
I/flutter (16526): context: LayoutBuilder(renderObject: _RenderLayoutBuilder#f6291 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT DETACHED)

E/flutter (16526): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (16526): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (16526): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter (16526): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3864
E/flutter (16526): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3878
E/flutter (16526): #2      Element.findAncestorStateOfType
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3926
E/flutter (16526): #3      Navigator.of
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2706
E/flutter (16526): #4      Navigator.push
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2116
E/flutter (16526): #5      _CourDelivReviewState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:storeifie/…/courierViews/courDelivReview.dart:560
E/flutter (16526): <asynchronous suspension>
E
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will works for you

```
  onTap: () async {
       String _courierOrderID = await model.placeCourierOrder(widget.orderInfoMap);
  
  
    await Navigator.push(context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CourierOrderSummaryView(singleCourierDataID: _courierOrderID),
             ),
         );
      },
```

Comment: It isn't helping man. The same output, don't know what to do now.

Comment: @FaizanKamal can you share your full code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
onTap: () async {
       String _courierOrderID = await model.placeCourierOrder(widget.orderInfoMap);
    // placeCourierOrder is just a Future<String> type function and it works fine. Order get placed successfully.
  
print("------- Courier Order Placed  " + _courierOrderID.toString());
print("context: " + _courierOrderID.toString());
  
  if(!mounted){
    print('you are not in this context anymore");
    // you changed the page and now you can't use this context.
  }
  Navigator.push(context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CourierOrderSummaryView(singleCourierDataID: _courierOrderID),
    ),
  );
},
```

Comment: The result of mounted is `true`. It means I can still use the context right? I don't know what to do now